# How can I add a ListBoxItem programmatically?

Tags: android, ios, delphi, firemonkey, listboxitem

I could only find how to create a `ListBoxItem` by clicking on the component -> **Items Editor**.

How can we create programmatically a `ListBoxItem` using `Firemonkey`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that a `ListBoxItem` is an item of an existing `TListBox` component named `ListBox1`, the item can be added like this:

```
ListBox1.Items.Add('an item name');
```

an alternative:

```
var
  id: Integer;

  . . .

  ListBox1.Items.AddObject('an item name', TObject(id));
```

**EDIT**
Notice that this approach has to be considered valid only if the underlying list is not sorted.

Comment: This is a VCL answer, but it's an FMX question. The question asks, *How can we create programmatically a ListBoxItem using Firemonkey?*

Comment: @DavidH tested with `FMX.ListBox.TListBox`

Comment: The framework converts Items.AddObject into code that creates a `TListBoxItem` and adds that. As a convenience. But if you create the `TListBoxItem` directly, you can do a lot more with it than just add text and data.

Comment: @DavidH `Items.Add` can be used as a convenience indeed; the listboxitem can obtained with `ListBox1.ListItems[n]` in any case

Comment: Sure. But if you want to set other than the text and data at the point of adding the item, then the convenience methods are lacking.

Comment: @fantaghirocco when creating them dynamically, how can I get a individual reference so I can set properties like Text `FontColor`?

Comment: @Holmes `ListBoxItem := ListBox1.ListItems[ListBox1.Count-1];`

Comment: @fantaghirocco this does not return the listitem object I think. Maybe I'm messing it up somewhere. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33344468/why-are-my-tlistbox-items-not-changing-their-color

Comment: If you want the item, why opt to do it the hard way?

Answer (score 11):

Simply create the list box item, and add it to the list box:

```
var
  ListBoxItem: TListBoxItem;
begin
  ListBoxItem := TListBoxItem.Create(ListBox1);
  ListBoxItem.Text := 'foo';
  // set other properties of the list box item at this point
  ListBox1.AddObject(ListBoxItem);
end;
```

Comment: The list box item can also be inserted anywhere in the list using:

`ListBox1.InsertObject(index, ListBoxItem)`

Comment: This is the correct answer and the other answer is terrible.

The "other properties" will include the item font size, which unlike VCL, is per item, instead of per control.

Answer (score 1):

I created ListBoxItem inside my ComboBox with some extra details:

```
var
    LBoxItem : Array [1..50] of TListBoxItem;

procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i: Integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to 10 do
  begin
    LBoxItem[i] := TListBoxItem.Create(ComboBox2);
    LBoxItem[i].Parent := ComboBox2;
    LBoxItem[i].Text := 'LBox'+IntToStr(i);
    LBoxItem[i].Font.Size := 18;
    LBoxItem[i].StyledSettings := [];
    LBoxItem[i].Height := 20;
  end;
end;
```