# Why are my TListBox items not changing their color?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, listboxitem

This is how I'm getting a few items from a List located on a local server.

I assume it still need some refactoring (sorry for being such a beginner in `Delphi`), however I would like to understand better why the `ListItem` **colors** are not being changed.

I did some debugging and found out that the `if` conditions are working fine for each color, and the `ListItem` is *receiving* it but I might be getting the wrong reference or using the wrong property to change the color.

Here's the full code:

```
procedure TFormLogin.TimerGetListTimer(Sender: TObject);
var
  genset_response: String;
  genset_amount: Integer;

  i: Integer;
  str_array: TStringDynArray;
  lb_item: TListBoxItem;

begin

  // Run this timer only 1 time for now
  TimerGetList.Enabled := false;

  // Clear all List items
  lb_gensets.Clear;

  // GET_LIST command to server
  IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.WriteLn('GET_LIST');
  // Server returns the List in a String
  genset_response := IdTCPClient1.IOHandler.ReadLn();

  // Remove all " from the String
  genset_response := StringReplace(genset_response, '"', '',
    [rfReplaceAll, rfIgnoreCase]);

  // Separate data by divider
  str_array := SplitString(genset_response, '|');

  // Get how many items
  genset_amount := StrToInt(str_array[1]);

  // Populate the List
  for i := 0 to (genset_amount - 1) do
  begin

    if (i = 0) then
    begin
      lb_gensets.Items.Add(str_array[2]);
    end
    else
    begin
      // Add items
      lb_gensets.Items.Add(str_array[i + 2]);

    end;

    // Get current ListItem
    lb_item := lb_gensets.ListItems[i];

    if (lb_item.Text.Contains('Online')) then
    begin
      // Set online items to Green color
      lb_item.TextSettings.FontColor := TAlphaColors.Mediumseagreen;
    end;

    if (lb_item.Text.Contains('OFF LINE')) then
    begin
      // Set Off Line items to Red color
      lb_item.TextSettings.FontColor := TAlphaColors.Red;
    end;

    // End of FOR
  end;

end;
```

Comment: maybe your list is *sorted* so the `i` variable does not match the index of the list anymore. `lb_gensets.ListItems[i]` does the same as `lb_gensets.ItemByIndex(i)`. In this case is safer to apply [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33284499/how-can-i-add-a-listboxitem-programmatically/33284984#33284984)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, controls use values from current style item (see `StyleLookup` property).

For use custom font color you must exclude `TStyledSetting.FontColor` from ListItem:

```
lb_item.StyledSettings:=lb_item.StyledSettings - [TStyledSetting.FontColor];
lb_item.TextSettings.FontColor := TAlphaColors.Red;
```

Comment: The correct way to get the item reference was : `lb_item := lb_gensets.ItemByIndex(i);`